# tabular side-by-side, same rows height

Tags: tables

Quick advise:

I want to have a tabular side-by-side.

How would you guys suggest me to go about making sure they have the same height?

Consider the case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{14.5em}}
\toprule
\textbf{Medidas Absolutas} \\
\midrule
Média dos erros quadrados \newline MSE$=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{x_i}-x_i)^2 $ \\
\midrule
Média dos desvios absolutos \newline MAD$=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |\hat{x_i}-x_i|$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{p{14.5em}}
\toprule
\textbf{Medidas Relativas} \\
\midrule
Coeficiente de Theil \newline U$=\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{x_i}-x_i)^2}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2}}$ \\
\midrule
Mean Absolute Percentage Error\newline MAPE$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \Big|\frac{(\hat{x_i}-x_i)}{x_i} \Big|$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Algumas medidas para avaliação do desempenho dos modelos preditivos.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

The problem is that the equations on the right are a little too big. I would like the corresponding row of the left table to have the same height.

I have tried `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}` is that it increases size to all rows, not just the bigger ones.

I have tried using `\phantom`, but it does not quite look for some reason ...

Maybe some `\mbox` with same height?

ps: these are some examples of absolute and relative error functions. If someone has some other idea to present this information that would be welcome as well!

Comment: just make them the same tabular with @{\hspace{2cm}] or some such space in the middle

Comment: with the 2015 latex release the example produces `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'.`  (You need the float package for `H`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\vphantom` can be used to adjust the row/line spacings of the two tables. This aligns the equation lines. Also some text lines nees `\vphantom` because of the descenders in the other table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{p{14.5em}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Medidas Absolutas} \\
    \midrule
    Média dos erros quadrados \newline MSE$=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n
    (\hat{x_i}-x_i)^2 $%
    \vphantom{$\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n}}$}
    \\
    \midrule
    Média dos desvios absolutos\vphantom{g}
    \newline MAD$=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n
    |\hat{x_i}-x_i|$%
    \vphantom{$\Big|$}
    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{p{14.5em}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Medidas Relativas} \\
    \midrule
    Coeficiente de Theil\vphantom{q} \newline
    U$=\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{x_i}-x_i)^2}}
      {\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2}}$
    \\
    \midrule
    Mean Absolute Percentage Error\newline MAPE$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n
    \Big|\frac{(\hat{x_i}-x_i)}{x_i} \Big|$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Algumas medidas para avaliação do desempenho dos modelos
    preditivos.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I did not know about `\vphantom`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use `\cmidrule`s throughout (in lieu of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`), then you can combine them into one `tabular`.

EDITED to clean up syntax, adding `{}=` for proper spacing and a `\displaystyle` for better vertical separation of fraction terms.

REEDITED to eliminate `\newline` from OP's approach, instead converting to two separate `tabular` rows, thus resulting in a better appearance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{14.5em}c@{\hspace{1cm}}p{14.5em}}
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
%\toprule
\textbf{Medidas Absolutas} &&\textbf{Medidas Relativas}\\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
Média dos erros quadrados  
&& Coeficiente de Theil \\
MSE${}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{x_i}-x_i)^2 $ &&
U${}=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{%
  \addstackgap[0pt]{\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{x_i}-x_i)^2}}}{\sqrt{\addstackgap[0pt]{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2}}}$\\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
Média dos desvios absolutos \newline MAD${}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |\hat{x_i}-x_i|$ 
&& Mean Absolute Percentage Error\newline MAPE${}=\frac{1}n\sum_{i=1}^n \Big|\frac{(\hat{x_i}-x_i)}{x_i} \Big|$\\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Algumas medidas para avaliação do desempenho dos modelos preditivos.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know about partial `\cmidrule` - very creative, thanks. But I am going with the other solution of using `\vphantom`. The table looks a bit better ...

Comment: @RicardoCruz Glad to have shown you an alternate technique.  Best wishes.

Comment: @RicardoCruz I did just revise my answer to convert your `\newline` cells into two separate rows.  This will result in more balanced spacing, as well.